# Which one is more correct? "a plaintiff pro se" or "a pro se plaintiff"?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style, latin

"Pro se" is Latin for "for self", or "for himself".

Therefore it makes more sense to me to use it in English as in "a plaintiff pro se".

However I have seen many cases in which "pro se" is used in English as an adjective, as in "a pro se plaintiff".

Which one is considered correct or more correct?

Comment: Bear in mind that *pro se* in legal contexts does not mean simply *for himself*; it is a technical term meaning appearing in court for himself. As it is effectively interchangeable with *unrepresented*, it is not surprising that it is sometimes treated syntactically the same say as  *unrepresented*.

Comment: Well, of course, in English one might write *plaintiff acting on their own behalf* and avoid the question altogether.  But if you must write in mixed English and Latin then perhaps do what legal practitioners do - follow established precedent.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark In legal documents I have seen both cases, but more as "a pro se plaintiff", maybe due to misunderstanding of the phrase. Which seems like they consider "a plaintiff pro se" as wrong. Is "a plaintiff pro se" wrong?

Comment: *rightness* and *wrongness* are not ways I assess sentences.  The test I'd apply in this case is *does the sentence (or whatever unit of text it is) clearly express the idea that it ought?* In so far as I am able to assess the horrid mixture of Latin and English either of the two forms you are mulling over is acceptable, they both mean the same thing and offer no room for misunderstanding.  Since you write that you find both in widespread use, choose one